# Weird animation glitch when I add display-inline Block to li items

Tags: css

When I add the display line-block attribute to my list items I get this weird animation glitch where it happens twice once I remove it, works fine again Gif Of "Glitch"
[image]

```
.title {
    font - size: 2rem;
    text - align: left;
    width: 100 % ;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    width: 75 % ;
    margin - right: 20em;
    display: inline - block;
    span {
        display: block;
    }@
    media(max - width: 1440px) {
        font - size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
li.services {
    list - style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 1em 2em;
    display: inline - block;
    vertical - align: middle; - webkit - animation: tracking - in -expand 0.7s cubic - bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1)
    0.5s both;
    animation: tracking - in -expand 0.7s cubic - bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1) 0.5s both;
}
    .services.Web - Applications\ & MobileApplications,
    .services.SearchEngineOptimization\ & Marketing,
    .services.Automation\ & Software {
        transition: all 0.2s ease - in -out;
}
    .services.Web - Applications\ & MobileApplications: hover {
        color: #49ff89;
      transform: scale(1.01);
    }
    li.services.SearchEngineOptimization\&Marketing:hover {
      color: # 10dafd;
        transform: scale(1.01);
}
    .services.Automation\ & Software: hover {
        color: #d61d9f;
        transform: scale(1.01);
}
```